# loop through a dict / fits show alert / stop on the half dict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Dict filled with the following content:

```
var seatsDict = {};

 seatsDict[5] = 5;
 seatsDict[5] = 10;
 seatsDict[5] = 1;
 seatsDict[1] = 20;
```

In HTML I have a select, which is structured like the following:

```
<select id="registerParticipants">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

What I actually want is that when the select field changes, I go through the dict with a for loop. If a value matches the selected value, I want to display an alert message.
Currently I try it like this:

```
$('#registerParticipants').change(function(){

  for(var key in seatsDict) {
    alert(seatsDict[key]);
    if(parseInt($(this).children("option:selected").val()) == seatsDict[key])
    {
      alert( 'fits' );
    }
  }
});
```

At the moment I get once '20' and once '1', then nothing happens. Do I have an error when going through the iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the object `seatsDict` have only two keys `5` & `1`. An object cannot have duplicate keys and doing this

```
 seatsDict[5] = 5;
 seatsDict[5] = 10;
 seatsDict[5] = 1;
```

will override the previous value

Also you can make minor change and dont need to iterate the object. Use `$('#registerParticipants').val()` to get the value of the `select`. Then check if the same key exist in the object

```js
var seatsDict = {};

seatsDict[5] = 5;
seatsDict[8] = 10;
seatsDict[7] = 1;
seatsDict[1] = 20;



$('#registerParticipants').change(function() {
  const selVal = $(this).val();
  if (seatsDict[selVal]) {
    alert('fits');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="registerParticipants">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```